# How can I add a delete function to this script to delete file on server

Tags: php, wordpress, file, unlink

i have a script which loads all files within a specific directory folder into a viewable table. I have also been able to successfully get the date uploaded element integrated and am using the $iterator function as seen in the code below

**UPDATE**

- edited value to checkbox input but still not working
- Removed unnecessary code snippets from past attempts
- Updated code to most recent and added full script for better understanding including CD001's suggestions

  ```
  // Begin Adding Uploader Page Content
  function pdfupload_admin_page(){
  ?>
      <style>
          <?php include '../wp-content/plugins/PDF-Uploader/support-files/stylesheet.css'; ?>
      </style>
      <div class="wrap">

      <div id="contact">



          <div style="text-align:center;">


          <h1>Secure PDF File Upload</h1>
          <p>Adding a watermark to your PDF files is as easy as uploading the file using the form below.<br>
          Upon successful submission of your PDF file you will receive the uploaded PDF files URL which you can then use when linking to the PDF within any page or post you desire.</p>
          <p>The PDF file when linked to using the URL provided will automatically acquire a watermark when loaded within the browser of the specific logged in user as well as the current date and time.</p>
          <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <h3>Select PDF File To Upload:</h3><br>
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload PDF File" name="submitUpload">
  </form>

  <?php

      $target_dir = "../wp-content/plugins/PDF-Uploader/";
      $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
      $uploadOk = 1;
      $FileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

      if(isset($_POST["submitUpload"])) {
          if (file_exists($target_file)) {
          echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
          $uploadOk = 0;
      }
      // Check file size
     // if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 10000000) {
      //    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
     //     $uploadOk = 0;
     // }
      // Allow certain file formats
      if($FileType != "pdf") {
          echo "Sorry, only PDF files are allowed.";
          $uploadOk = 0;
      }
      // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
      if ($uploadOk == 0) {
          echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
      // if everything is ok, try to upload file
      } else {
          if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
              echo "File uploaded successfully use the following URL when linking to your PDF <br> https://website.com/wp-content/plugins/PDF-Uploader/watermarked.php?filename=" . basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). "";
          } else {
              echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
          }
      }
      }
      // Check if file already exists

      /**
       * FILE DELETION HANDLER  
       */
     $iterator = new FilesystemIterator('../wp-content/plugins/PDF-Uploader/');

      function delete_file($iterator, $file) {
          if(!unlink($iterator->getPath() . '/' . $file)) {
              echo "Sorry! your file cannot be deleted. Please try again later";
          }
          else {
              echo "File deleted successfully!";
          }
      }
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
          if(!empty($_POST['file'])) { // check if the checkbox was checked.
              foreach($_POST['file'] as $file) {
                  // call delete function here.
                  delete_file($iterator, $file);
              }
          }
          else{
              echo "No file selected. You must select at least one PDF file to be deleted.";
          }
      }


  ?>


      </div>
  <?php
   // if ($handle = opendir('../wp-content/plugins/PDF-Uploader/')) {
   //     while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
   //    {
   //        if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && strtolower(substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1)) == 'pdf')
   //       {
    //          $thelist .= '<td><input type="checkbox" name="file[]" value="https://website.com/wp-content/plugins/PDF-Uploader/'.$file.'"></td>';
    //      }
    //  }
  //    closedir($handle);
  //}
  ?>
  <form id="deletionForm" method="post" action="">
  <table>
  <thead>
          <tr style="width:100%;">
              <th style="width:25px;"></th>
              <th style="text-align:left;width:625px;">Filename</th>
              <th style="text-align:right;width:100px;padding-right:20px;">Date Uploaded</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
  <?php
      // $iterator = new FilesystemIterator('../wp-content/plugins/PDF-Uploader/pdf-watermarker/');
      foreach($iterator as $file){
          //if($file->isFile()){
          if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && strtolower(substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1)) == 'pdf')
          {
              $cTime = new DateTime();
              $cTime->setTimestamp($file->getCTime());
              //echo $file->getFileName() . " file Created " . $cTime->format('Y-m-d h:i:s') .  "<br/>\n";
  ?>
          <tr>
              <td style="width:25px;"><input type="checkbox" name="file[]" value="wp-content/plugins/PDF-Uploader/<?php echo $file->getFileName(); ?>"></td>
              <td style="text-align:left;width:625px;"><a href="https://website.com/wp-content/plugins/PDF-Uploader/<?php echo $file->getFileName(); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $file->getFileName(); ?></a></td>
              <td style="text-align:right;width:100px;padding-right:20px;"><?php echo $cTime->format('Y-m-d h:i:s'); ?></td>
          </tr>

  <?php
  }
      }
      ?>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete Selection">
  </form>
      </div>

      <?php
  }
  // End Adding Secure PDF Upload Page Content
  ```

So all in a nutshell, I need to figure out why the delete functionis not working and add a sort order to the script to product the results in alphabetical order.

Any code samples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your date is in a `<td>`, put it in an input if you want it sent in the form

Comment: *"So all in a nutshell, I need to figure out how I can add the delete function to the first code snippet..."* ... copy/paste? I get the feeling I'm not really understanding the question mind...

Comment: made the edit to the code, in the end I have the file connected to the checkbox and when you click the checkbox and submit I am trying to have it delete that file so not sure if the date is needed as an input or not but probably would be a better option for sorting the order I am guessing. thanks for the spot.

Comment: Date in the form isn't really relevant I don't think - you're reading the *creation time* from the file itself using `$file->getCTime()`

Comment: hi CD001 the delete function worked with my old code but not with the new one and am trying to figure out why. I hope that clarifies

Comment: Oh - possibly because you're passing in the full filepath in the `file[]` input array - looking at it I think you should only have the filename.

Comment: Though actually `$iterator` is out-of-scope in the `delete_file` function.

Comment: so in the checkbox input change the value to just the file and not the path? will give it a go :) sometimes you just need another set of eyes I tell ya.

Comment: what would be the alternative if $iterator and delete_file are out of scope as you noted?

Comment: file handling requires a valid enctype, your form doesn't contain one. You're also using the wrong superglobal for the file array.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution (explanation follows)**

```
<?php 
// global iterator
$iterator = new FilesystemIterator('../wp-content/plugins/PDF-Uploader/');

function delete_file($iterator, $file) {
    if(!unlink($iterator->getPath() . '/' . $file)) {
        echo "Sorry! your file cannot be deleted. Please try again later";
    }
    else {
        echo "File deleted successfully!";
    }
}

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['file'])) { // check if the checkbox was checked.
        foreach($_POST['file'] as $file) {
            // call delete function here.
            delete_file($iterator, $file);
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "No file selected. You must select at least one PDF file to be deleted.";
    }
}
?>

<form method="post" action="">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr style="width:100%;">
            <th style="width:25px;"></th>
            <th style="text-align:left;width:625px;">Filename</th>
            <th style="text-align:right;width:100px;padding-right:20px;">Date Uploaded</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<?php
    foreach($iterator as $file) {
        //if($file->isFile()){
        if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && strtolower(substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1)) == 'pdf')
        {
            $cTime = new DateTime();
            $cTime->setTimestamp($file->getCTime());
            //echo $file->getFileName() . " file Created " . $cTime->format('Y-m-d h:i:s') .  "<br/>\n";
?>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:25px;"><input type="checkbox" name="file[]" value="<?= $file->getFileName(); ?>"></td>
            <td style="text-align:left;width:625px;"><a href="<?= $file; ?>" target="_blank"><?= $file->getFileName(); ?></a></td>
            <td style="text-align:right;width:100px;padding-right:20px;"><input type="text" name="date[]" value="<?= $cTime->format('Y-m-d h:i:s'); ?>"></td>
        </tr>

<?php
}
    }
    ?>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete Selection">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Explanation**

Since the `FilesystemIterator` holds the path to the directory for your PDF repository I've defined that as a global variable at the top of the script. It's then referenced wherever required so should you ever need to change the filepath, you just change it in the `$iterator`.

For instance, it's used in the loop and passed to the `delete_file` function. The form itself is only posting the filenames rather than the full paths.

Otherwise you weren't really a long way off.

**Couple of thoughts**

The `FilesystemIterator` class has methods for detecting the extension and whether the file is `.` or `..` so you can replace:

```
if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && strtolower(substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1)) == 'pdf')
```

With:

```
if(!$file->isDot() && $file->getExtension() == 'pdf')
```

Which is a little neater.

There is also a security concern with having a directory that's both web server readable and writeable - if there's a vulnerability in your application an unauthorised user could upload and execute anything (open it in the browser); a malicious PHP script for instance.

You can mitigate this through your Apache configuration - one common thing to do is to disable PHP via an `.htaccess` file:

```
php_flag engine off
```

Comment: You should see the comment I posted to the OP; you missed a few things, as did they.

Comment: will check this out and thanks for the tip Funk, do you have a resource link I can check out on that one?

Comment: @DigitalDesigner Try CD001's answer again; he edited.

Comment: I added the elements noted in CD001's post to my page as well as the initial question but still not deleting, no errors in log, just the validation error message on the page saying it can't be deleted. did I implement it incorrectly?

Comment: @DigitalDesigner - it looks like you're still sending up the full filepath for the file to be deleted rather than just the filename, e.g. `wp-content/plugins/PDF-Uploader/<?php echo $file->getFileName(); ?>` - I made a few changes in the `<tr>` output for the image list as well...

Answer (score 2):

File handling require a valid enctype in `<form>`, being `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as per the manual:

- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

An example from the manual:

```
<!-- The data encoding type, enctype, MUST be specified as below -->
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="__URL__" method="POST">
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

You need to change all references of `$_POST['file']` to `$_FILES['file']['name']` / `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` respectively.

Handling multiple files is also included in the manual, and here is an example pulled from it:

```
<?php
// In PHP versions earlier than 4.1.0, $HTTP_POST_FILES should be used instead
// of $_FILES.

$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}

echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";

?>
```

Use PHP's error reporting to help you debug:

- https://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

However, when dealing with checkboxes, don't use `empty()`, use `isset()`:

```
if(isset($_POST['file'])) { // check if the checkbox was checked.
```

It's a bit unclear if you want to upload files. If so, then you need to change the `<input type="checkbox"` to an file input type `<input type="file"`

**Edit:**

This part of your code should error out, since there needs to be an empty variable declaration using `$thelist = "";`

I.e.:

```
<?php 

    if ($handle = opendir('../wp-content/plugins/PDF-Uploader/.')) {

    $thelist = "";
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
        {
            if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && strtolower(substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1)) == 'pdf')
            {
                $thelist .= '<td><input type="checkbox" name="file[]" value="../wp-content/plugins/PDF-Uploader/'.$file.'"></td>';
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks Funk, as with all new avenues, there is always a learning curve somewhere. I will review and make my script stronger for it :)

Comment: @DigitalDesigner welcome. However... after reviewing your code in more depth, I may have been wrong here. However, I did make an edit about your checkboxes and you will need to reload it. Try that out, if it doesn't work, then I'll try and be of more help as I can.

Comment: @DigitalDesigner if that failed to helping in a solution, I will delete my answer. I wouldn't want to lead you in the wrong direction here. If `$_FILES` failed, then change it back to `$_POST`, but do check for errors and try the other answer given.

Comment: Yeah - I had to nip out so I couldn't really answer fully. With this form though, no files are actually being uploaded - just the filenames (or paths) so they can be deleted from the server, so you don't really need to worry about the form being multipart ;)

Comment: Good call on `isset()` though if the checkbox can have a valid *"falsey"* value.

Comment: @CD001 True. I'm hoping we can come up with a solution for the guy.